# Why was Uranus named what it was?

Tags: naming, uranus

Why was Uranus named what it was, and who came up with the name?

Comment: https://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/StarChild/questions/question42.html Maybe check this out. It has some information that you might be looking for. This link too: http://coolcosmos.ipac.caltech.edu/ask/136-How-did-Uranus-get-its-name-

Comment: I'm suggesting you read this Wikipedia article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus#Name

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more fit for History of Science and Mathematics.

Comment: Typing the question in the body into a search engine immediately gets an answer and it's hard to see what people can't do something that simple before creating a new question on SE.  Surely the search engine is quicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Herschel, the discoverer of the planet named it Georgium Sidus, "George's star" after his patron, King George III of Great Britain.

The name was not popular outside of Great Britain, and there were various other proposals. It was Johann Elert Bode who proposed Uranus, the Latin form of the Greek god of the sky.  It fits with the existing planets having the names of Roman Gods, and just as Saturn was the father of Zeus, so Uranus was the father of Saturn.